# How to redeploy tensorflow-serving with new version of model and access it via http post

Tags: docker, tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

I have one model already deployed and running on tensorflow-serving docker .
Now I want to re-deploy that model with new and improved model.

I have deployed the previous model with below command:

```
docker run -p 8501:8501 --mount type=bind,source=/opt/scripts/testing/models/model01/,target=/models/my_model -e MODEL_NAME=my_model -t tensorflow/serving
```

New model is saved in /opt/scripts/testing/models/model02/

Comment: please explain what you want clearly, where is the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you already have a `Saved Model` in the path, `/opt/scripts/testing/models/model01/`.

Now, you have updated/improved the model and saved it in the path,  `/opt/scripts/testing/models/model02/`.

Now you want to deploy New Version of your Model.It is simple, in the `Docker Run command`, replace `model1` with `model2` as shown below:

```
docker run -p 8501:8501 --mount type=bind,source=/opt/scripts/testing/models/model02/,target=/models/my_model -e MODEL_NAME=my_model -t tensorflow/serving
```

You can access the Model via `http post` as shown below (example):

```
curl -d '{"instances": [1.0, 2.0, 5.0]}' \
    -X POST http://localhost:8501/v1/models/my_model:predict
```